# Module debugging should be disabled when shipping static libraries iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am getting lots of warnings in my app saying

> "note: Module debugging should be disabled when shipping static
>   libraries"

I don't know what it means.I have a framework created by me inside the main project.How can I get rid of all these warnings?

Screenshot is attached.It shows some error related to Google IMA sdk as well.

[image]

Comment: What if you run it in release mode, do you still these warnings

Comment: Yes.While making archive also the warning appears.

Comment: It seems it is related to GoogleAds framework